# trap -p or -l command outputs nothing

Tags: terminal, command-line

When I run `which trap`, it outputs shell built-in command.

```
$ which trap
trap: shell built-in command
```

According to [the manual](https://ss64.com/osx/trap.html):

> If arg is not present and -p has been supplied, then the trap commands associated with each sigspec are displayed. If no arguments are supplied or if only -p is given, trap prints the list of commands associated with each signal.

But when I run `trap -l` and `trap -p`, it outputs nothing.

On Ubuntu, I get all signals.

```
 1) SIGHUP   2) SIGINT   3) SIGQUIT  4) SIGILL   5) SIGTRAP
 6) SIGABRT  7) SIGBUS   8) SIGFPE   9) SIGKILL 10) SIGUSR1
11) SIGSEGV 12) SIGUSR2 13) SIGPIPE 14) SIGALRM 15) SIGTERM
16) SIGSTKFLT   17) SIGCHLD 18) SIGCONT 19) SIGSTOP 20) SIGTSTP
21) SIGTTIN 22) SIGTTOU 23) SIGURG  24) SIGXCPU 25) SIGXFSZ
26) SIGVTALRM   27) SIGPROF 28) SIGWINCH    29) SIGIO   30) SIGPWR
31) SIGSYS  34) SIGRTMIN    35) SIGRTMIN+1  36) SIGRTMIN+2  37) SIGRTMIN+3
38) SIGRTMIN+4  39) SIGRTMIN+5  40) SIGRTMIN+6  41) SIGRTMIN+7  42) SIGRTMIN+8
43) SIGRTMIN+9  44) SIGRTMIN+10 45) SIGRTMIN+11 46) SIGRTMIN+12 47) SIGRTMIN+13
48) SIGRTMIN+14 49) SIGRTMIN+15 50) SIGRTMAX-14 51) SIGRTMAX-13 52) SIGRTMAX-12
53) SIGRTMAX-11 54) SIGRTMAX-10 55) SIGRTMAX-9  56) SIGRTMAX-8  57) SIGRTMAX-7
58) SIGRTMAX-6  59) SIGRTMAX-5  60) SIGRTMAX-4  61) SIGRTMAX-3  62) SIGRTMAX-2
63) SIGRTMAX-1  64) SIGRTMAX
```

How can I output macOS trap signals?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Short Answer

Your link appears to be for `bash`. The latest versions of macOS now use `zsh` as the default shell. The table below summarizes possible `zsh` equivalents.

| Orignal bash | Close zsh Equivalent |
| --- | --- |
| **trap -l** | **for sig in $(kill -l); do printf "%2s) SIG$sig\n" $(kill -l $sig); done** or **bash -c 'trap -l'** |
| **trap -p** | **trap** |
| **trap -p** *sig* | **trap | grep -E** *sig***$** |
| **trap -p** *sig1 sig2* ... | **trap | grep -E -e** *sig1***$ -e** *sig2***$** ... |

### Longer More Detailed Answer

Your link appears to be for `bash`. The latest versions of macOS now use `zsh` as the default shell.

Under `zsh`, the command below will list the signal names.

```
kill -l
```

For example, the above command produces the following output

```
HUP INT QUIT ILL TRAP ABRT EMT FPE KILL BUS SEGV SYS PIPE ALRM TERM URG STOP TSTP CONT CHLD TTIN TTOU IO XCPU XFSZ VTALRM PROF WINCH INFO USR1 USR2
```

---

Also, the command below will list the corresponding signal number for each `sig` that is a name.

```
kill -l [ sig ... ]
```

For example, the command

```
kill -l INT QUIT ILL TRAP ABRT
```

will produce the following output.

```
2
3
4
5
6
```

You can enter `man zshbuiltins` to get help with the `trap` and `kill` builtins for `zsh`.

---

When you entered `trap -l`, the command `-l` was associated with no signals. This can be shown to be true by adding a signal to the `trap -l` command, as shown below.

```
trap -l USR1
```

Here, the command `-l` is associated with the `USR1` signal. This can be demonstrated by entering the command given below. This command prints the list of commands associated with `USR1` signal

```
trap | grep -E USR1$
```

The output from the above command is given below.

```
trap -- -l USR1
```

Normally, the command `-l` would not exist.

---

The commands below would produce output similar to using the `bash` builtin  `trap -l`.

```
for sig in $(kill -l); do printf " '%2s) SIG$sig'" $(kill -l $sig); done | xargs printf "%-15s %-15s %-15s %s\n"
```

The output from entering the above command is given below.

```
 1) SIGHUP       2) SIGINT       3) SIGQUIT      4) SIGILL
 5) SIGTRAP      6) SIGABRT      7) SIGEMT       8) SIGFPE
 9) SIGKILL     10) SIGBUS      11) SIGSEGV     12) SIGSYS
13) SIGPIPE     14) SIGALRM     15) SIGTERM     16) SIGURG
17) SIGSTOP     18) SIGTSTP     19) SIGCONT     20) SIGCHLD
21) SIGTTIN     22) SIGTTOU     23) SIGIO       24) SIGXCPU
25) SIGXFSZ     26) SIGVTALRM   27) SIGPROF     28) SIGWINCH
29) SIGINFO     30) SIGUSR1     31) SIGUSR2
```

I suppose the above commands could be wrapped in a function, as shown below.

```
trap-l() { local sig; for sig in $(kill -l); do printf " '%2s) SIG$sig'" $(kill -l $sig); done | xargs printf "%-15s %-15s %-15s %s\n"; }
```

This would allow the output to be produced by just entering `trap-l`. However, this might just be folly, since apparently you could have simply entered the command `bash -c 'trap -l'`.